# React-native-mmkv with RN 0.71.13

Tags: android, react-native, c++11, cmake, node-modules

When I try to compile an android application, the react-native-mmkv error occurs. Versions rn@0.71.13, rn-mmkv @2.6.1:

Screen with error: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6oX5.png)

Text error:
[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\projects\iteco_employee\node_modules\react-native-mmkv\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot\bin\java" ^
--class-path ^
"C:\Users\�����\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.prefab\cli\2.0.0\f2702b5ca13df54e3ca92f29d6b403fb6285d8df\cli-2.0.0-all.jar" ^
com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt ^
--build-system ^
cmake ^
--platform ^
android ^
--abi ^
arm64-v8a ^
--os-version ^
21 ^
--stl ^
c++_shared ^
--ndk-version ^
23 ^
--output ^
"C:\projects\iteco_employee\node_modules\react-native-mmkv\android\.cxx\Debug\102y6045\prefab\arm64-v8a\prefab-configure" ^
"C:\Users\�����\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\424a954c875c180c05cfd9ac51146e77\transformed\jetified-react-android-0.71.13-debug\prefab" ^
"C:\Users\�����\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c9bd024e1950645d86b630b5a7b35a74\transformed\jetified-fbjni-0.3.0\prefab"
from C:\projects\iteco_employee\node_modules\react-native-mmkv\android
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt

Comment: Please, add the error message to the question post as **text**. The *image* is insufficient. See also [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.